# Can I add an enum to an existing .NET Structure, like Date?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums, extension-methods

So apparently Microsoft does not have a Months Enum on their Date structure.
What I am wondering is, is it possible to create an enum and attach it to the DateTime structure?  Extension Methods come instantly to mind, but I don't know of a way to pull this off using them.

```
Dim july As DateTime.Months = DateTime.Months.July

Public Enum Months
    January = 1
    February = 2
    March = 3
    April = 4
    May = 5
    June = 6
    July = 7
    August = 8
    September = 9
    October = 10
    November = 11
    December = 12
End Enum
```

Any one have any thoughts on this?

Update:
I am not trying to get the Month name of the current Month or of a given date.  I know how to do that.  I was just trying to create a class that had a Month property and wanted to use an Enum to represent the month.  Since this seems like an item that could have usefulness elsewhere, I hate to put the Enum into my class and would rather have it be "located" in the structure that it is directly related to so that it could be found easily.
Thank you for all the responses.  I should have been more clear up front as to what I wanted to do.

Comment: What would it even *mean* to "attach" an enum to the structure? It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You cannot extend DateTime considering its a structure. You don't need to. **Months October = (Months)DateTime.Now.Month** would work.  Of course there already is ToString functions to do exactly this so its sort of pointless.

Comment: @JonSkeet: He means he wants to make it appear that his `Months` enum is nested within the `DateTime` class so he can use the syntax in the first line of his code sample.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: But it's not clear why that would be a good thing, rather than just having a Months enum *not* as a nested type.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There are [built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx) [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) for turning the int month number into a name.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - It would take 5 extra characters to make the line he wants to use compile.  There is no purpose in doing what he wants, we must prevent silly ideas from being used, its our job as programmers.

Comment: Of course the names of months are culturally-dependant. It doesn't really matter which culture the names used internally come from (they're only in code), and Quakers and some other Non-Conformist Protestants used 1, 2, 3 (or sometimes "First Month", "Second Month") to avoid the English names which are based on Roman Paganism. Therefore the numbers used by the code as-is are already the names used by one group of English-users anyway. Problem already solved! ;)

Comment: @Ramhound: Hey, I'm not saying he's right, and I upvoted the comments and answers saying he shouldn't even try. I just figured I'd help clarify what he wanted, since Jon didn't know what he meant by "attach an enum".

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: You are correct as to what I am trying to accomplish.  Whether or not I should do this is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @Ramhound: _"silly ideas from being used"_  Maybe its not a best, or even a recommended practice, but I don't know if I would call it a  "silly idea", especially with as little as information as I provided.  I certainly would not call it that if I was trying to be respectful.  I believe "our job as programmers" is to mentor one another in a respectful manner.  Nonetheless, I thank you for your response and am stepping off my soapbox.

Comment: @Airn5475 - You asking a vague question is not my fault, replied as a comment to advise you with less information then an answer would required, yet what you want to do already exists.  I feel it is my job to say, yeah your idea is silly, so you don't pratice bad habits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add properties to an existing type like that.

You can, however add an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that will convert from integers to the corresponding Enum value, or simply return the enum value corresponding to the month.

Comment: Thank you for simply answering my question. This is what I was afraid of, but I wanted to check nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Extension method stub:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
   public static string GetMonthName(this DateTime dateTime)
   {
       // add using System.Globalization;
       return DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName(dateTime.Month);
   }

   public static Months GetMonth(this DateTime dateTime)
   {          
         return (Months)dateTime.GetMonthName();          
   }
}
```

Usages:

```
DateTime mydate = dateTime.Now;    
string month = mydate.GetMonthName();
Months name = mydate.GetMonth();
```

Comment: `return (Months)dateTime.Month;`

Comment: @Oded : right if such enum exists and return value should be `MonthEnum`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx

Comment: Your GetMonth method only seems to return anything if it is January

Comment: @Chris Dunaway : yep this is an example, anyway I've updated that. thanks

Comment: I think `GetMonth` should be implemented as `(Months)dataTime.Month`, as Oded suggested. Casting from a localizable string to an enum doesn't compile and is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an extension like this:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{    
    public static Months GetMonth(this Date dt)
    {
        return (Months)dt.Month;
    }
    public static Months GetMonthStr(this Date dt)
    {
        return ((Months)dt.Month).ToString();
    }
}
```